# CSS: How do I make a !100% header with a repeat-x background and tip

Tags: css, background, width

I'm creating a website for a client - I have yet never experienced problems that I could not fix, but after 3 hours of trying and searching, I decided to ask here.

So, I have made a mockup in Photoshop.
[Desired design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwG6v.png)

The grid is my main content/center of the page, but I want to have the header only fit from left (0px) to the end of my grid container, and also have a "tip" at the end (the arrow)

I decided to use a 1x99px background for the whole background and the actual image for the tip, mainly to avoid spending too much data on the image (as the page will contain tons of images)

I have given it a shot, and did some HTML/CSS, but it either ended in a wrong layout (the header grid-container being wrongfully placed), shadows overlaying or the tip exceeding the grid-container.

My header:

```
<div class="header_bg"></div>
    <header>
        <div class="header-content">
            <div class="grid-container">
                asdads
                <div class="header_arrow"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

My CSS:

```
header {
    height: 99px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: calc(50% + 50%);
    position: relative;
}

.header_arrow {
    background: url(images/header_arrow.png) no-repeat;
    width: 144px;
    height: 99px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -156px;
}

.header_bg {
    background: url(images/header_bg.png) repeat-x;
    height: 99px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
}

header .grid-container {
    height: 99px;
    background: url(images/header_bg.png) repeat-x;
}
```

How it appears:
[Current design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhDAI.png)
With the red boxes being grid-container

It's almost what I'm looking for, but I want the end/tip to be inside the grid-container and the shadows to stop overlaying.

Any ideas? Thanks you so much!

Comment: use `background-size` to achieve this

Comment: Thanks you, how exactly would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give the `.grid-container` a right margin equal to the width of the `.header_arrow`, and make the right margin of that equal to its width

```
header .grid-container {
    height: 99px;
    background: url(images/header_bg.png) repeat-x;
    margin-right:144px;
}
.header_arrow {
    background: url(images/header_arrow.png) no-repeat;
    width: 144px;
    height: 99px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -144px;
}
```